# Total Area of the Region Bounded by the Curves - Need some assistance

Tags: calculus, integration

*This is not a homework question. This is from a test from a previous year, in an attempt to learn the material.

Find the total area of the region bounded by the curves y = 3/x and y = 4-x

To start off, I figured I'd need to find the points of intersection, in order to find the actual area I'm trying to solve.

On the right side of the x axis, x = 1 and x = 3 are the points of intersection. On the negative side, they will never intersect. This leaves me confused as to the actual area I'm attempting to solve.

Pretty much, I don't even know where to start, and even if I find that, I'm doubtful I'll be able to finish.

My current assumption, I'm trying to find the area between the interval [1,3]?

Update : This is a guess, but seems semi correct? The integral from 1 to 3 of (3/x) - (4-x)

Take the anti derivatives, separate, end up with

the integral from 1 to 3 of ln abs(3x)   - the integral from 1 to 3 of (4x - x^2 / 2)

.. the integral from 1 to 3 of (4x - x^2 / 2) seems to equal 4, assuming my math was correct, meaning that the area would be equal to (ln9-ln3) - 4? That would give a negative number, so I'd guess it would actually be 4 - (ln9-ln3), which is roughly 2.9

Am I going about this the completely wrong way?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to decide what line is above the region and what is below. This is needed for signs in formula $S = \int_a^b(f(x) - g(x))dx$. Here $f(x)$ bounds the region from above while $g(x)$ from below. $a$ and $b$ are points of intersection and they can be found by solving equation $f(x) = g(x)$ for $x$. As you correctly wrote, $[a,b] = [1,3]$.
Are you able continue by yourself from here?

Answer (score 0):

First of all where do the two graphs intersect? If you set them equal it will lead you to the two solutions $1$ and $3$. First of all I would evaluate the area in the interval [1,3] under the function $f_1(x) := 4-x$. Then find the area under the function $f_2(x) := 3/x.$
I think these steps should be very intuitive, even without calculus/analysis knowledge.

Let's move on to the main dish - the integrals. Let's call our desired area $A$. Then
$$A = \int_{1}^{3}4-x\,\mathrm{d}x \, - \int_{1}^{3}3/x\,\mathrm{d}x.$$

I think the first integral shouldn't be a problem. You can spit it up into two futher integrals and evaluate these with basic calculus. The second integral shouldn't be hard too if you know that the antiderivative of $1/x$ is $\log\lvert x\rvert + C$. [Bonus: Don't forget that you will get a small problem if u take the antidervative of $1/x$ while integrating over $0$.]